# Pass props with callback from Parent to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this parent `App.jsx`, with two components `<Child1/>` and `<Child2/>` imported.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = React.useState(false);
  
  const handleSelectPlayers = () => {
    setIsFlipped(true);
  }

  const handleDeselectPlayers = () => {
    setIsFlipped(false);
  }

  return (
    <Flippy
      isFlipped={isFlipped}
      flipDirection="horizontal" // horizontal or vertical
      style={{ width: "400px", height: "600px" }} /// these are optional style, it is not necessary
    >
      <FrontSide>
        <Child1 onSelectPlayers={handleSelectPlayers} /> // <-----
      </FrontSide>
      <BackSide>
        <Child2 onDeselectPlayers={handleDeselectPlayers} /> // <-----
      </BackSide>
    </Flippy>
  );
}
```

---

This is `Child1.jsx`, where I have 'players' set locally by `this.setState()`:

```
class Child1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      players:[]
    };
  }

  async getPlayers() {
      const res = await fetch("/json/players.json");
      const data = await res.json();
      const players = Object.values(data.Players)

        this.setState({ 
          players: players
        },() => console.log(this.state.players));
      }

    handlePlayers = () => {
        this.props.onSelectPlayers();
      };

    render() {
        return (
        ...
        <Button handleClick={() => this.handlePlayers()}></Button>
        ...
        );
```

---

And here `Child2.jsx`, which needs 'players' as `props`, given the fact they are fetched at `Child1.jsx`.

```
class Child2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      players:[]
    };
  }


 handlePlayers = () => {
    // do something with players here
  };

handleChangePlayers = () => {
    this.props.onDeselectPlayers();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Button handleClick={() => this.handlePlayers()}> 
      <Button handleClick={() => this.handleChangePlayers()}>
      ... 
    );
  }
```

---

I know I can achieve this by having a callback to `App.jsx` at `Child1.jsx`, so I can pass players as props to `Child2.jsx`, but how so?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: are `Child1` & `Child2` siblings? and they have common parent `App`?

Comment: I don;t know what you mean by 'siblings', sorry...I use the terminology to show hierarchy

Comment: I mean is your structure something like this `<Parent><Child1/><Child2/></Parent>`?

Comment: yes, I guess so...

Comment: please refer to my edit. `<Child1/>` and `<Child2/>` are now properly refered to at `<Parent>`.

Comment: you can move up  the `players` state to the Parent and pass them down as props to the children

Comment: yes, but how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the `players` state on the Parent of both Child components. This way, you can pass it down as props to the relevant components. Refer to my comments on the code for insight

```js
function App(){
  const [players, setPlayers] = React.useState(); // single source of truth for players
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child1 setPlayers={setPlayers}/> // pass state setter to Child1 where you perform the xhr to fetch players
      <Child2 players={players}/> // pass players down as props to Child2
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

class Child1 extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getPlayers(); // sample fetching of players
  }

  getPlayers() {
    this.props.setPlayers([ // set players state which resides on the parent component "App"
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]);
  }
  
  render() {return "Child1"}
}

class Child2 extends React.Component{

  componentDidUpdate(){
    // this.props.players contains updated players
    console.log(`Child2 players`, this.props.players);  
  }

  render() {return "Child2"}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```